# Subscription for newBlocks golang

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I have followed [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/rpc/client_example_test.go) guide and wrote the same code but instead of getting the latest block, I am getting this,

```
Subscription Failed =>  The method newBlocks_newBlocks does not exist/is not available
```

Code :

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc"
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "context"
)

type Block struct{
    Number string
}

func main(){
    clientSubscription()

}
func clientSubscription(){
    client, err := rpc.Dial("ws://localhost:8546")
    //client, err := rpc.Dial("ws://115.186.176.139:8547")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Connecting to Server",err)

    }
    subch:=make(chan Block)
    go func(){
        for i:=0; ; i++{
            if i>0 {
                time.Sleep(2*time.Second)
            }
            subscribeBlocks(client,subch)
        }
    }()

    for block:=range subch{
        fmt.Println("Latest Block => ",block.Number)
    }

}

func subscribeBlocks(client *rpc.Client, subch chan Block)  {
    ctx,cancel:=context.WithTimeout(context.Background(),10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    blockSubscription,err:=client.EthSubscribe(ctx,subch,"newBlocks")
    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Println("Subscription Failed => ",err)
        return
    }

    var latestBlock Block
    if err:=client.CallContext(ctx,&latestBlock,"eth_getBlockByNumber","latest"); err!=nil{
        fmt.Println("Cannot get the latest Block => ",err)
        return
    }

    subch <-latestBlock

    fmt.Println("connection lost",<-blockSubscription.Err())
}
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a full working example of how to subscribe to latest blocks using the go-ethereum package in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    headers := make(chan *types.Header)
    sub, err := client.SubscribeNewHead(context.Background(), headers)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for {
        select {
        case err := <-sub.Err():
            log.Fatal(err)
        case header := <-headers:
            block, err := client.BlockByHash(context.Background(), header.Hash())
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            fmt.Println(block.Hash().Hex())        // 0xbc10defa8dda384c96a17640d84de5578804945d347072e091b4e5f390ddea7f
            fmt.Println(block.Number().Uint64())   // 3477413
            fmt.Println(block.Time().Uint64())     // 1529525947
            fmt.Println(block.Nonce())             // 130524141876765836
            fmt.Println(len(block.Transactions())) // 7
        }
    }
}
```

For more examples, check out the the [Ethereum Development with Go book](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book).